# Google Map won't display on mobile devices but work fine on PC Browsers

Tags: php, android, jquery, iphone, google-maps

I have the beginning of a mobile app working great on my PC in IE and Chrome.  When I switch to either my iPhone (safari) or Android (native browser) devices and view the exact same URL the map does not display.  I've tried everything I can think of with no luck.  Can someone please take a look and tell me what I am missing?

URL:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me on Nexus S running Android 4.1.1 using the default browser

Comment: odd, I get a blank space where the map should be

Comment: It was a version issue with the jquery plugin and version of Anroid.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it on my Iphone and it accurately showed my location, is this what you wanted to accomplish??

Comment: for me, I get only a blank space.  this is just weird.